# Feasibility of pushing notifications from web application to desktop windows forms application using SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, notifications, signalr

I want to build a notification system between Web application and a desktop Winforms application.

I want my web application to push notifications into my Windows Forms Desktop application, and at the same time I want to filter the messages that will be delivered to the users.  I mean not all connected users will receive all messages. There will be a filtration process that will occur on the server side (web application) to determine who will receive what.

I want the desktop app to receive the notifications if is already connected, and if not it will receive nothing.  I don't want to save the notifications that will come from the server if the app is not connected or is not running.  The Pushed notifications will be instant and will not be saved on the client side, they will be just displayed.

Also I have a concern: if multiple users are connected and are requesting from the server at the same time, will that affect the performance of the server?

There will be 20,000 users, for example, using the Windows Forms app to receive the notifications depending on their categories from the server side (Web Application).

Does SignalR supports this scenario?

Comment: did you tried and get final solution ***with high performance*** for your scenario ( 20.000 users, ASP.NET push to WinForms) ? Would you like *sharing* _good patterns and practices_ about it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does SignalR supports this scenario?

Yes it supports and it's suitable for live time notifications.

You can use [groups](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups) for broadcasting messages to specified subsets of connected clients. But don't use groups for sensetive data.

You can [track/map](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) connected clients and just send messages to specific user/users notification by connectionId/connectionIds.

If we come to performance, 20000 concurrent connections (I asssume concurrent) it's really many. First you should [change IIS configuration](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Performance) to support more than 5000 concurrent requests.

You should [optimize signalr for performance](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance). The message size should be less. The per message should be maximum 4 Kb (I suggest you to use more less for this many concurrent connections).

Signalr uses `Json` so you can use `JsonProperty` to reduce messsage size.

```
[JsonProperty("op")]
public decimal OrderPrice
```

Why message size is important ? Because every connection has a buffer on server side. If client can get 1 messsage but at that time server sends 2 messages, messages will be filled in the buffer. These buffers use memory. Therefore, you should be more carefully with 20000 concurrent connections. Otherwise you will suffer from memory consumption.

But in your stiuation, message size will be not enough also you should decrease this bufffer limit.

> **DefaultMessageBufferSize**: By default, SignalR retains **1000** messages in
>   memory per hub per connection. If large messages are being used, this
>   may create memory issues which can be alleviated by reducing this
>   value. This setting can be set in the Application_Start event handler
>   in an ASP.NET application, or in the Configuration method of an OWIN
>   startup class in a self-hosted application. The following sample
>   demonstrates how to reduce this value in order to reduce the memory
>   footprint of your application in order to reduce the amount of server
>   memory used:
>
> ```
> public class Startup
> {
>     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
>     {
>         // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
>       GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize = 500;
>       app.MapSignalR();
>     }
> }
> ```

I suggest you to use it 100. What's drawback of decreasing buffer limit ? When buffer is full, it will not get any new messsage. That's mean client will loose some of your notifications. So if your notifications are transactional(User has to recieve), don't decrease buffer size many. But if not, you can decrease (Minumum has to be 32).

You should use net 4.5 or higher both on server and client sides and your clients should have windows8 or higher to support websocket.

After apply these steps, follow your memory consumption and change messsage size/buffer limit/frequency of messsages.

**Bonus:** 20000 concurrent requests are too many. Therefore I suggest you to use load balancer/scaleup and [Signalr BackPlane](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr), If you face performance problem. That's way, you will have not 1 web server let's say 4. Each will have 5000 concurrent requests (averagely). When you send one message on a server the other servers (also their clients) will get the message with backplane. What's drawback ? You should use shared resource (eg: database) to track/map users with connectionIds.